# Strange Behavior with sceen sizes for different Android devices

Tags: android, view, compatibility, android-canvas, ondraw

I am a college student working on a final project for android development.

My project is a simple game of snake where the user can use the accelerometer, or buttons.

The way my game view works is I create a grid dynamically, on my "SnakeView" which extends view like such:

```
/**
 * This is where we paint the grid and the game.
 */
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if(created){
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mPaintScreen);
    mBitmap.eraseColor(Color.WHITE);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < xlength; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < ylength; j++){
            int x = i * rectWidth;
            int y = j * rectHeight;
            Point p = new Point(i,j);
            if(snake.contains(p)){
                mBitmapCanvas.drawRect(x,y, x + rectWidth, y + rectHeight, mSnakePaint);
            }else if(walls.contains(p)){
                mBitmapCanvas.drawRect(x,y, x + rectWidth, y + rectHeight, mWallPaint);
            }else if (growBerries.contains(p)){
                mBitmapCanvas.drawRect(x,y, x + rectWidth, y + rectHeight, mGrowBerryPaint);
            }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Basically I have an arraylist that contains the snake and my berries.
If the point on the plain is in either arraylist, I paint the rectangle a different color. Otherwise I keep the plane white.

For setting rectWidth and height I go in the onSizeChanged method.

```
@Override
public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldW, int oldH){
    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mBitmapCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    mBitmap.eraseColor(Color.WHITE);
    width = w;
    height = h;
    rectWidth = width / (xlength-1);
    rectHeight = height / (ylength-1);
    invalidate();
}
```

now the issue is the blocks do not format to the correct size accross different devices.
I have tested this on the nexus 7 tablet (not sure dimensions but its much larger), and my phone which is a pantech flex. (roughly 4 inches)

[image: myimage]

[image: myimage2]

As you can see, the one on the right, the outer border i created doesn't match up to the screen width.
I was wondering why this could be.

I definitely know the borders are hugging my grid, it is just that the grid is not spread out to fit the whole width.

This should work and the sizes should fit according to screen size. My only guess is that the int w and int h, are rounded off, and they do not protray the actual width and height.
xlength and ylength are the number of blocks I want in the x and y direction.

I noticed that if I adjust the amount of rectangles, it may fit on one device, but not the other, I just want it to fit perfectly on both!

Comment: Where do you get all the dimensions from? (xlength, ylength, etc.)

Comment: xlength and ylength is the amount of squares I want on the grid.
they are sent from my Main Activity.

Comment: I suspect you get the dimensions and perform your calculation incorrectly in some way. To make any use of it, you will need to show that piece of code, or better yet: Start by painting the screen without these rects, and see in which part of your calculations the mistakes start happening.

Comment: i showed the code containing the calculations in my edit.
it is in my onSizeChanged method.

Answer (score 2):

What happens if you change the **size** of the rectangles? My first guess is that rectWidth is not evenly divisible by the width of the screen, which is why there is whitespace along the border.

If this is the case, then you could probably fix it by defining rectWidth and rectHeight to be a function of the screen's dimensions (although if you're not careful this could mean that different devices have a different sized playing area. I'm not sure if you want to avoid that or not).

Comment: See my edit, I forgot to mention that the rectWidth and height is decided based on the actual screens width.

Comment: How is walls defined? Your issue is likely that it is not being defined correctly to include the borders of the screen.

Comment: walls is a linkedlist of points. It opens up the data from an XML file. 
it is set though so the walls are on the border of the dimensions.

I currently have xlength at 35, and I set the wall's location at (34, y)

We lay the grid out from x = 0 to 34
I am pretty sure the walls are not really the issue with it, they definitely are hugging the border of the grid, it is the problem of the grid not stretching out properly to fit the width.

Comment: This probably won't change anything, but in `onSizeChanged` aren't the parameters w and h the new width and height of the view? Why do you need to call `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` in that method if they already give you that?

That couldn't be screwing things up, could it? `getWidth()` couldn't be giving you a different value than w for some mystical reason, could it?

Comment: yeah I fixed it so it i set mbitmap equal to w and h now. no difference. I'm wondering if this will ever be able to be fixed.